# Lucene query parser not parse field as expected

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, query-parser

I want to parse a simple query using lucene (3.0.3):

```
title:(+return +"pink panther")
```

Just like in the documentation example.

The expected result is:

```
+title:return +title:"pink panther"
```

But instead i get:

```
+title:return +title:"itle return pink panther"
```

The code is very simple (c#):

```
Query query = 
    new QueryParser(
        Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, 
        "content", 
        new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
    .Parse("title:(+return +\"pink panther\")");
```

Comment: Your code looks fine as far as I can tell.  What call are you making that returns `+title:return +title:"itle return pink panther"`?

Comment: the query object (ToString()) is returned that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, the issue was a custom-modified Lucene.Net assembly...

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this. Does this still occur for you?

I'm thinking that it may be some display artifacts from the output window. Is this from the Immediate Window, the Watch Window or a call to Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Hi, thanks, it shows on all options (Immediate Window, Watch Window or and Console.WriteLine command window)

Comment: @Omri, could you provide a screenshot where this occurs? Does this occur even if it's a single statement in a freshly created console application?